# Adding a guess loop to my Javascript number guessing game

Tags: javascript, numbers

I'm pretty new at Javascript and I've built a simple number guessing game. The program generates a random number between 1-10 and prompts you if your guess is too high or too low. If you guess right, you win.

I'd like to improve on this current version by giving the player 3 guesses, after which the player either wins, or loses. I know this is done with loops, but I can't for the life of me figure out how. I've tried using while loops but it doesn't work. Here is my code and thank you all for your help:

```
    <script>
    var rannum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); //generates a random number and stores it in the rannum variable

        function submitanswer(){  //This function analyzes player response and is called by the submit button
            var playerguess = document.getElementById("guess"); //grabs whatever the player types in and stores it in the playerguess variable
            if (playerguess.value == rannum){ //if the value of playerguess is the same as rannum then the player wins
                alert("You win!");
                location.reload();
            }
            if (playerguess.value > rannum){ //if the player's guess is higher than the random number alert too high
                alert("Too high!");
                document.getElementById("guess").value='';
            }

            else if (playerguess.value < rannum){ //if the player's guess is lower than the random number alert too low
                alert("Too low!");
                document.getElementById("guess").value='';
            }


        }
        function reloaD(){ //start over by generating a new number
            document.getElementById("guess").value='';
            location.reload();
        }                           

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use a loop. Wait for the user to do an action such as *press a button* or *hit enter after they typed a word*. Then *continue* with the logic: is the guess correct? if not, have they guessed wrong too many times? if so, then GAME OVER.

Comment: For starters, create an initialisation function you can call so you do not have to reload. You cannot use a loop, just a counter you set to 3 and call init when it is 0. The init will have your generator, and the resetting of the counter

Answer (score 0):

So here is how i went on about your game.. i will try my best to make you understand my logic.

First of all, you need an input box where user will input his/her guess and a button to submit that guess:

```
Your Guess: <input type='text' id='guess'>
<button id="checkBtn">Check</button>
```

Then an event listener on button click. In that, im getting the value of the user's guess from input box and sending it to another function which will check whether the guess is correct, low or high. Also i am keeping a counter which will increment on each button click. And the user will be able to check only till maxGuesses, initially 3. When counter equals max guesses, that's when the game ends and im disabling the button so no more input.

```
document.getElementById('checkBtn').onclick = function (){
    var guess = document.getElementById('guess').value;
    checkGuess(guess);
    counter++;

    if(counter == maxGuesses) {
        alert("Game Over");
        document.getElementById("checkBtn").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

checking the guess for too high, low or correct guess is simple logic as used by you, three conditions. On the correct guess, user will be displayed "You Win!" and the button will get disabled again because game ended now.

```
function checkGuess(guess){
    if (guess == rannum){ //if the value of playerguess is the same as rannum then the player wins
        alert("You win!");
        document.getElementById("checkBtn").disabled = true;
    }
    if (guess > rannum){ //if the player's guess is higher than the random number alert too high
        alert("Too high!");
        document.getElementById("guess").value='';
    }

    else if (guess < rannum){ //if the player's guess is lower than the random number alert too low
    alert("Too low!");
         document.getElementById("guess").value='';
     }
}
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/f77dkbj0/)**

*EDIT:* I added the restart functionality as well. By adding a restart button which is initially hidden `display: none`

```
<button id="restart" style="display:none">Restart</button>
```

It will get displayed when either the user wins or the Game gets over (max guesses reached).

```
document.getElementById("restart").style.display='block'; //making it visible
```

Then when the user clicks on restart, all the values reset, restart button disappears and the game begins again.

```
document.getElementById('restart').onclick = function (){
    rannum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    counter = 0;  
    guess = 0;
    document.getElementById("checkBtn").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("guess").value='';
    document.getElementById("restart").style.display='none';
}
```

**[See the new DEMO with restart option here](http://jsfiddle.net/f77dkbj0/1/)**

Comment: Thank you for this, I wasn't aware of counters and now I have something to look into. I thought that loops were the only way of solving my problem, but I'll keep counters in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use loops here. You can just use a variable that tracks how many guesses are still left. You decrease the variable by one each time you compute the answer. If it gets to 0, the game is lost.

I also made some other improvements to your code, namely:

- Using a separate JS file for the code.
- Wrapping the code in an immediately-invoked function expression so that no global variables are leaked.
- Gave the variables some more readable names.
- Fetched the DOM elements from the DOM only once.
- Replaced alert() in favour of putting the answer directly in a DIV.
- Removed the page reload - it's not necessary here, you can just reset the game's state.

File index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Guess the number</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="guess" />
            <input type="submit" id="submitAnswer" value="Check answer" />
        </form>
        <div id="answer"></div>
        <script src="game.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

File game.js:

```
(function () {

    var guessesLeft, randomNumber, guessInput, submitButton, answerDisplay, maxGuesses;

    maxGuesses = 3;

    // Load all the element references from the DOM
    // so that we don't need to do that every time we chek the answer
    guessInput = document.getElementById("guess");
    submitButton = document.getElementById("submitAnswer");

    // Let's use a DIV element to display the answer.
    // It's nicer than using alert().
    answerDisplay = document.getElementById("answer");

    answerDisplay.innerHTML = "Please make a guess!";

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        checkAnswer();
    });

    initGame();

    function initGame () {
        guessesLeft = maxGuesses;
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        guessInput.value = "";
    }

    function checkAnswer () {

        if (guessInput.value == randomNumber) {
            answerDisplay.innerHTML = "You win! " + randomNumber + " is correct. " +
                "Please input your next guess to start again.";
            initGame();
            return;
        }
        else if (guessInput.value > randomNumber) {
            answerDisplay.innerHTML = "Too high!";
        }
        else {
            answerDisplay.innerHTML = "Too low!";
        }

        guessesLeft -= 1;

        if (guessesLeft === 0) {
            answerDisplay.innerHTML += " No guesses left - you lost!";
            initGame();
        }
    }

}());
```

Comment: Some things here are new to me like the addEventListener function. But I'll research that on my own. Thank you for making these improvements to my coding as it's a good practice to master good coding conventions earlier on.

Comment: The .addEventListener() function in this case does almost the same as the onclick= attribute on an HTML element or the .onclick property of a DOM element in JS. The biggest difference is that you can add more than one listener using .addEventListener() which makes it a much better fit if you want to combine scripts in your web app because they might need to listen for the same event. It also gives you an event object in your callback which you can use to control how events behave in a limited fashion. event.preventDefault() in this case prevents the submission of the form.